# How to show password in an EditText where current inputType is "textPassword"?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I know there are a lot of questions very similar to this, but then none of them seem to have worked for me. 
When I check the box, I want the password to be visible. When I uncheck it, I want the dots instead of actual characters.
As of now, I only have dots.

I am getting the following nullpointerexception.

```
07-08 15:08:50.441: E/AndroidRuntime(4518): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 15:08:50.441: E/AndroidRuntime(4518): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 15:08:50.441: E/AndroidRuntime(4518):     at com.passwordkeeper.ui.ActivityPreferenceScreen$1.onPreferenceClick(ActivityPreferenceScreen.java:65)
07-08 15:08:50.441: E/AndroidRuntime(4518):     at android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:951)
07-08 15:08:50.441: E/AndroidRuntime(4518):     at android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:215)
```

This is my code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void setFields(){
    mPasswordField = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.loginPwdEditText);
    showPwd = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("checkBox");
    showPwd.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            if(showPwd.isChecked()){        
                Log.v("showpwd", "apparently its checked");
                mPasswordField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            }
            else{
                Log.v("showpwd", "apparently its not checked now");
                mPasswordField.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD );
                    }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

The log is working. So it is actually printing "apparently its checked" when i check the box. But then, it gets stuck and the null pointer exception shuts down the app.

Any help would be useful!

Answer (score 0):

This code is wrong:

```
mPasswordField.setInputType(129);
mPasswordField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

As second set overwrites first one. Flags have to be OR'ed:

```
mPasswordField.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD );
```

As for NPE, you most likely ends with

```
mPasswordField
```

being `null`, hence the exception.

Comment: Yeah, I realise that code was wrong. But it still doesn't work. I've rechecked that my mPasswordField is not null.

Answer (score 0):

To display password:

```
 if(showPwd.isChecked()){
    if(mPasswordField!=null)
       pass.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
}
else
    pass.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to move

```
mPasswordField = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.loginPwdEditText);
```

inside `onPreferenceClick(Preference preference)` method

Comment: Nope, that isn't working. It still gives me the same nullpointerexception.

Comment: mPasswordField is null? Could you say in which line do you have NPE?

Comment: At this line:
mPasswordField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);

Comment: My mPasswordField is not null though. I've rechecked that. I'm able to use setText and change the contents of the field.

Comment: You should to use debugger to understand which varible is null.But im sure that mPasswordField is null, because InputType cant be.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Just put this 1 line of code on your check condition-

```
btnCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            editPsw.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is working code for me I am using this on my application on click of a button..
if this is not work for you some thing wrong in your code..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. It works PERFECTLY

```
    cb_Visible_password
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                       et_confirmpassword.setTransformationMethod(null);
                    } else {

                        et_confirmpassword
                                .setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod
                                        .getInstance());
                    }
                }
            });
```